# Feature importances from dummy variables (after using get_dummies or dictVectorizer)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, dummy-variable

Random Forests have the excellent [feature importances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html), but after using a One Hot Encoder (such as [preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) or Pandas' [get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) I (naturally) get one importance per dummy variable.

Is there a way to rebuild the feature importance of a full feature from the importances of its dummy variables?

Comment: Its actually sum of all dummies in  `get_dummies` and `preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` but ` DictVectorizer` does not create dummies it encodes binaries i guess